# problem with the getting data from firestore into recyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement a message page into my app. I take the messages from Firestore. When the user clicks on the RecyclerView item, isMessageRead value is changed to true. Everything is working but the problem is when read the boolean value from Firestore using model class, all of the values are coming false. what did I miss? thanks.

[image: this is model class]

[image: this is firestore messages data]

[image: this is screenshot from the app]

```
class NotificationAdapter(
    var notificationList: List<NotificationModelClass>,
    private val clickListener: (NotificationModelClass) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    var notifications: List<NotificationModelClass> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        val myView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.notification_layout, parent, false)

        return ChaplainsViewHolder(myView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        (holder as ChaplainsViewHolder).bind(notifications[position], clickListener)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return notifications.size
    }

    fun submitList(notificationList: List<NotificationModelClass>) {
        notifications = notificationList
    }

    class ChaplainsViewHolder constructor(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        private val notificationTitle = itemView.title
        private val notificationMessage = itemView.message
        private val notificationTime = itemView.messageTime
        private val notificationImage = itemView.logo
        private val notificationCardView = itemView.notificationCardView
        private val notificationMessageRead = itemView.imageViewMessageRead

        fun bind(
            notificationInfo: NotificationModelClass,
            clickListener: (NotificationModelClass) -> Unit
        ) {
            notificationTitle.text = notificationInfo.title

            notificationMessage.text = notificationInfo.body

            val messageTime = notificationInfo.dateSent
            val dateFormatLocalZone = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm - MMM dd, yyyy")
            dateFormatLocalZone.timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
            val timeRangeFirst = dateFormatLocalZone.format(Date(messageTime!!.toLong()))
            //notificationTime.text = timeRangeFirst.toString()

            Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.logo).into(notificationImage)

            notificationTime.text = notificationInfo.isMessageRead.toString()
            /*if (isMessageRead == "no"){
                notificationMessageRead.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_mic_24)
            }*/

            notificationCardView.setOnClickListener {
                clickListener(notificationInfo)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to map a document into an object of type `NotificationModelClass` it means that each field in the class will be initialized with the value of the corresponding field that exists in the document. Since the `isMessageRead` field is already initialized with the value of `false`, when deserializing the value of the field will always be `false`. To solve this you have to change:

```
var isMessageRead: Boolean? = false,
```

To:

```
val isMessageRead: Boolean? = null,
```

In this way, you'll initialize the field with a value that comes from the database and not with the default one.